# Spoon.bat não funciona com windows 7 e java 1.8

Tags: java, windows, pentaho

Apos descompactar o PDI do Pentaho. Tento executar o spoon.bat e recebe esta mensagem abaixo e não abre a IDE

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando o java 1.8 e windows 7 64bits

**Mensagem de erro:**

> DEBUG: Using JAVA_HOME DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161 DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\javaw.exe
>
> start "Spoon" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\javaw.exe" 
>   "-Xms1024m" "-Xmx2048m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
>   "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
>   "-Djava.library.path=libswt\win64" "-DKETTLE_HOME="
>   "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=" "-DKETTLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD="
>   "-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT="
>   "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=" -jar
>   launcher\pentaho-application-launcher-6.1.0.1-196.jar -lib
>   ..\libswt\win64

**Arquivo PATH:**

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\GNU\SSH;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
>   Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
>   Live;C:\orant\bin;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Tcl\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\cvsnt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program
>   Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Skype\Phone\;%M2%;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME%

Comment: Já tentou executar o script como administrador?

Comment: Já tentei executar com Administrador e recebo  a mesma mensagem

Comment: Olá! Forneça o erro como texto na sua pergunta, ao invés de usar uma imagem. Assim, no futuro, as pessoas que procurarem pelo mesmo erro irão encontrar sua pergunta.

Comment: foi inserido a mensagem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguir resolve este problema no ketller criando uma variável PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME no path do sistema e apontei pra o JRE.
Apos este simples configuração conseguir fazer roda o Kettler.